# Implicit conversion error from string to timestamp in Datastage

Tags: type-conversion, etl, datastage, ibm-infosphere

I am facing timestamp conversion error in IBM Infosphere datastage parllel job. Input is sequential file and column holds varchar datatype. Below is the value when you view the data from sequential file.

Input value : Jun 30 2022  5:19AM

I want to convert to Timestamp in below format while loading to output file

Expected Output : 2022-07-30 05:19:00.0

What can I try next? I have tried different type conversions ended with either implicit conversion or doesn't match format.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the format in which the timestamp data are being received, as part of the StringToTimestamp() function.

```
StringToTimestamp(inLink.MyValue, "%yyyy-%mm-%dd %dd-%nn-%ss.s")
```